# DEPS_RESOLVE_FAILED on module when building a web application with Brunch in ES6

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, vue.js, brunch

I'm having an issue when building my web application using [Brunch](http://brunch.io). My application depends on a module I've created and uploaded to [NPM](http://www.npmjs.com), and whenever I build it, I get:

```
DEPS_RESOLVE_FAILED of node_modules/rd-vue-bootstrap/dist/rd-vue-bootstrap.js failed. 
Could not load module './bs-button-group.vue' from '/Users/rjuliani/dev/production-manager-ui/node_modules/rd-vue-bootstrap/dist'. 
Make sure the file actually exists
```

The module itself builds just fine, however when I use it from my test web application and build it (the web application) it throw me the above error.

The relevant parts of my package.json file for the module are:

```
"main": "dist/rd-vue-bootstrap.js",
  "files": [
      "dist/rd-vue-bootstrap.js",
      "dist/rd-vue-bootstrap.js.map",
      "dist/rd-vue-bootstrap.min.js",
      "src"
  ],
```

**brunch-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    files: {
        javascripts: {
            joinTo: 'app.js'
        },
        templates: {
            joinTo: 'app.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        babel: {

        },
        assetsmanager: {
            copyTo: {
                'vendor': ['node_modules/bootstrap', 'node_modules/jquery', 'node_modules/rd-vue-bootstrap']
            },
            minTimeSpanSeconds: 10 // assets won't be copied more frequent than once per X seconds.npm
        }
    }
};
```

**initialize.js (main file for my web application)**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import RdVueBootstrap from 'rd-vue-bootstrap';

Vue.use(RdVueBootstrap);
```

**Finally, package.json for my test web application**

```
{
  "name": "production-manager-ui",
  "description": "Simple UI for the production-manager API project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/radical-dreamers/production-manager-ui.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "brunch watch --server",
    "build": "brunch build --production"
  },
  "author": {
    "url": "http://www.codelightsoftware.com",
    "name": "Rodrigo Juliani",
    "email": "srodriki@gmail.com"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "vue",
    "brunch"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "rd-vue-bootstrap": "0.0.6",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assetsmanager-brunch": "^1.8.1",
    "auto-reload-brunch": "^2.7.1",
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.6",
    "brunch": "^2.8.2",
    "css-brunch": "^2.6.1",
    "javascript-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-brunch": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-devtools": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I've tried many things and nothing seems to be working as of right now :(

Thanks!

Comment: So far I've just been able to find that  the exception is thrown in my rd-vue-bootstrap's main module export: 

    export default BsVueBootstrap;